# PropType is defined but prop is never used - But it is?

Tags: eslint, flowtype, airbnb-js-styleguide

I am getting those errors but I have no idea how to fix them. This is how I define and use the property in question:

```js
type State = {
  isLoading: boolean // <-- 'isLoading' PropType is defined but prop is never used
};
type Props = {};


export default class MyComponent extends Component<State, Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isLoading: true };
  }
 render() {
    const {isLoading } = this.state; // <-- property `isLoading` is missing in  `Props` [1].Flow(InferError)
index.js(25, 52): [1] `Props`
    if (isLoading)
      return (
        <Container>
          <Spinner color="blue" />
        </Container>
      );
 }
}
```

So there are defined and they are used (when I am destructuring). I also do not understand the Flow error, but they are obviously related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reversed the order of `Props` and `State` type parameters that you passed to the `Component`, so Flow thinks props is `State` and state is `Props`. That line should look like this, with `Props` first followed by `State`:

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component<Props, State> {
    // ...
}
```

Check out the [Flow docs on React components](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/) for more.